# SML tuples - Combination

Tags: sml, smlnj

I've come across a tuples problem where given a list of pair tuples it should become a pair of lists: i.e. `[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]` should return `([1,3,5],[2,4,6])`.

I've tried to solve it using this code:

```
 fun convert L = foldl (fn(a,b) => #1a::b) [] L;
```

But I get an error saying: unresolved flex record.
Anyone able to explain why I'm getting this and how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `a`, the compiler can tell it's supposed to be a tuple (since you're calling `#1a`), but it can't tell how big it is. The SML type system doesn't allow tuples of unknown size; you need to make it clear that `a` is a pair.

While you could resolve this just by giving `a` a type declaration, the nicer way of doing it is to pattern-match it. Instead of defining you argument as `(a,b)` and using `#1a` and `#2a`, define your argument as `((x,y),b)` and use `x` and `y`.

There's another issue with your solution, however. Your function is adding the first element of the pair to a result list, but you're ignoring the second element (`#2a`), and your result lacks a second list. The function you're passing to `foldl` should be `fn ((x,y),(u,v)) => ...`, and your initial value should be `([],[])`.

---

The reason for that cryptic error message, "unresolved flex record", is that tuples in SML are implemented as records with integer labels. The tuple `(a,b)` is *identical* to the record `{1=a,2=b}`. And in fact, if you type `{1=1,2=2}` into the SML/NJ shell, it will return

```
val it = (1,2) : int * int
```

So when you say `#1a`, you're really saying "extract the element with the label `1` from the record `a`".

SML/NJ has no concept of [record polymorphism](http://www.pllab.riec.tohoku.ac.jp/smlsharp/?FeatureRecordPolymorphism). It understands that `a` must be a record, and that this record type must at least contain the label `1` (and potentially others), but there's no way to express this in the SML/NJ type system.

So the compiler needs to know the exact structure of the record in order to infer a type for `a`, and if it can't figure it out, it throws an "unresolved record" error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an SML interpreter handy, but I think that you are looking for [`unzip`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list-pair.html#SIG%3aLIST_PAIR.unzip%3aVAL).  Try:

```
unzip([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]);
```

IIRC, "unresolved flex record" had to do with record matching which you aren't using here?!  Take a look at the error docs for smlnj (http://www.smlnj.org/doc/errors.html).  You will need to search for error `[99]` near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
- ListPair.unzip([(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]);
> val it = ([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]) : int list * int list
```